# how to read json data from a link and passing that data to django

Tags: django, json, django-models, django-forms

I have link(127.0.0.1:8000/read) which contains json data.how to read a json data from link and pass that values to django form.

Comment: What does "from a link" mean? You don't have a GET parameter there in the example URL. What did you try already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is very rough - and without understanding what your requirements are, its hard to place a read example. But this is a simple example of how to get some json:

```
import urllib2
import json

req = urllib2.Request('http://127.0.0.1:8000/read')
r = urllib2.urlopen(req)
data = r.read()
j = json.loads(data)
node = j['node']['child_node']
for element in node:
    print "Element node information: %s" % element['child_node']

#An example of saving information to send to your form
form_text = j['parentnode']['copy']['formtext']
```